# URLSession and UI related tasks

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to authenticate login by retrieving a boolean from my web server using URLSession, and show an Alert Controller if the login fails.

```
func requestLogin() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://mywebserver/login.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(txtUsername.text!)&password=\(txtPassword.text!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            self.promptMessage(message: "No data found")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                let success = jsonData.value(forKey: "success") as! Bool
                if (success) {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in
                        //Move to next VC
                    })
                    return
                } else {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in
                        self.promptMessage(message: "The username or password that you have entered is incorrect. Please try again.")}
                    )
                    return
                }
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in
                    self.promptMessage(message: "Error: Could not parse JSON!")
                })
            }
        } catch {
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in
                self.promptMessage(message: "Error: Request failed!")
            })
        }
    })
    showOverlayOnTask(message: "Logging in...")
    task.resume()
}

func promptMessage(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login Failed", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showOverlayOnTask(message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The weird problem I'm getting is that my Logging In alert controller **sometimes does not dismiss**. It gets stuck until I tap on the screen, which then will dismiss and show the next alert controller. It's very annoying and I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

How do I fix this?

Comment: is requestLogin called on main thread ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I don't think so. How do i call this on the main thread? Earlier on i had an error which was about main thread too. The error was: NSInternalInconsistencyException accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread

Comment: I don't see any alert action on the alert created in `showOverlayOnTask` method. Maybe once you add a ok action similar to which you did in `promptMessage` method would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you're trying to dismiss the controller without executing on the main thread, normally the UI changes/updates should be executed on the main thread.

Try this and check if works:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in
            self.promptMessage(message: "Error: Could not parse JSON!")
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar and I noticed that when I add this into my dataTask that I get the following error: Value of type 'ContentView' has no member dismiss referring to the self.dismiss line. Any idea how to fix that?